# "A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto" ao filtrar array

Tags: c#, regex

Após mandar uma String que é uma palavra chave de comando ao meu Arduino pela porta serial,estou tentando pegar valores em uma aplicação em C#, e uma determinada string e coloca-los em dois arrays diferentes utilizando expressões regulares, no entanto esta dando o seguinte erro na marca vermelha no codigo abaixo:"A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto."
Segue o codigo  abaixo:
Se puderem ajudar, agradeço.

```
void SerialPort1DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {

    RxString += serialPort1.ReadExisting(); //le o dado disponível na serial.Sempre recebe os dados adicionandono final do buffer
    if (RxString.StartsWith("@")) {
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(trataDadoRecebidoComandSimples)); //chama outra thread para escrever o feedback de comando realizado com sucesso no text box
    }
    if (RxString.StartsWith("#")) {
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(trataDadoRecebidoComandDistancia)); //chama outra thread para escrever o feedback de comando realizado com sucesso no text box
    }
}
public void limpaStringComandos() {

}

public void trataDadoRecebidoComandSimples(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //depois de receber os dados verifica se possui uma mensagem completa nele, ou seja, o feedback do arduino que o comando foi realizado com sucesso. Ex: Navio 01 Leme a vante executado com sucesso - (OKNULAV)
    //devemos fazer isso em um loop pois pode acontecer de chegar mais de uma mensagem ao mesmo tempo

    int identificador = 0;
    while ((identificador = RxString.IndexOf('@')) >= 0) {
        txtMonitor.Text = RxString;
        //separamos a primeira mensagem do identificador sem o delimitador
        string mensagem = RxString.Substring(0, identificador);
        //tratamos ela da forma que for necessário, no caso, alimentar o txtDistancia com a informação limpa de acumulos de dados.
        txtStatus.Text = mensagem;
        //por fim removemos ela do buffer
        RxString = RxString.Substring(identificador + 1);
    }

}
public void trataDadoRecebidoComandDistancia(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int identificador = 0;
    while ((identificador = RxString.IndexOf('#')) >= 0) {
        string patternDistancia = @ "^\#[A-Z]{1,7}\r\n\#[A-Z]{1,9}\#"; //Retira os caracteres excedentes e deixa no array somente "numero#" ex.: 17#17#18#...
        string patternDistanciaRetorno = @ "^\#[A-Z]{1,7}([0-9]{1,3}\#){10}"; //Retira os caracteres excedentes e deixa no array somente "#feedback do Arduino#" ex.: #OKNUSAPRO#
        Match m = Regex.Match(RxString, patternDistancia);
        while (m.Success) {
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }
        string[] SDistancia = Regex.Split(RxString, patternDistancia, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string[] SRetorno = Regex.Split(RxString, patternDistanciaRetorno, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string SString = string.Concat(SDistancia);
        string SStringRetorno = string.Concat(SRetorno);
        String[] SVetor = SString.Split('#');
        int cont = 0;
        int media = 0;
        int soma = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
            cont = cont + 1; * * int caracter = Int32.Parse(SVetor[n]); // aqui ocorre o erro**
            soma += Convert.ToInt32(caracter);
        }
        media = soma / cont;
        txtDistancia.Text = media.ToString();
        txtMonitor.Text = RxString;
        //separamos a primeira mensagem do identificador sem o delimitador
        string mensagem = SStringRetorno.Substring(0, identificador);
        //tratamos ela da forma que for necessário, no caso, alimentar o txtDistancia com a informação limpa de acumulos de dados.
        txtStatus.Text = mensagem;
        //por fim removemos ela do buffer
        SStringRetorno = SStringRetorno.Substring(identificador + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você sabe disser um que parte do código ocorre este erro? para resumir um pouco o problema.

Comment: Eu não compreendi a parte do `Match m = Regex.Match(RxString, patternDistancia);`, pois fora dentro do `while`, `m` não é utilizado.

Comment: Neste ponto no código, dentro deste for:             for (int n = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
            cont = cont + 1; * * int caracter = Int32.Parse(SVetor[n]); // aqui ocorre o erro**
            soma += Convert.ToInt32(caracter);
        }

Comment: Guilherme, no caso este match é só pra verificar se a string entro nos parâmetros que coloque na expressão regular.Mas eu ja comentei esta parte do código e deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Exceção 'A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto' ao fazer cálculo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166603/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-cadeia-de-caracteres-de-entrada-n%c3%a3o-estava-em-um-formato-correto-ao)

Answer (score 4):

Isso quer dizer que você está tentando converter para `int` alguma `string` **que não seja um número**. Você só precisa conferir sua string com atenção e descobrirá o erro.

Tente debuggar o código, mostrar o valor na tela ou no console (`Console.WriteLine()`) antes de converter vai ser bem mais fácil de achar o causador do erro.

---

#### Sobre a mensagem de erro

A mensagem de erro em português é meio idiota mesmo e o pior é que ela é assim desde que eu conheço .NET.

A mensagem:

> A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto

Na verdade, deveria ser

> A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato **correto**

A mensagem original, é:

> Input string was not in a correct format