# Exceção 'A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto' ao fazer cálculo

Tags: c#

Eu estou tentando fazer este cálculo, usando C#:

> ((x+50)/100)*50(x²-5x+8))

Fiz deste jeito:

```
double Morte = ((int.Parse(TextBox1.Text) + 50) / 100) *50*(Math.Pow(int.Parse(TextBox1.Text),2)-5*int.Parse(TextBox1.Text)+8);
```

Mas toda vez que eu rodo o programa e faço o teste, ele me da este erro:

> System.FormatException: 'A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.'

Comment: Precisamos saber o que tem nos campos na hora que você executou esse código.

Comment: não aquilo eu estava testando dividir a conta esqueci de tirar xD.

Comment: quando eu digitar no textbox um numero 56 por exemplo,ele tem q me retornar um valor.qualquer número que eu coloco ele da esta exceção.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que `TextBox1.Text` deve ter um valor **que não pode ser convertido em número**. Tente validar isto, imprimí-lo na tela ou no console antes de tentar converter para número.

Meu palpite é que tenha um espaço em branco no início ou no fim.

Pra evitar esse tipo de coisa, você pode usar um **`TryParse`**. O `TryParse` retorna `true` se a conversão foi bem sucedida e `false` caso contrário.

Veja um exemplo.

```
int valorDigitado;
bool conversaoSucedida = int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out valorDigitado);

if(!conversaoSucedida)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Valor digitado é inválido");
    return;
} 

double morte; // = cálculo;
```

Talvez também fosse interessante usar outras abordagens, algumas em conjunto com esta, mas não tem como dar muita dica sem ter mais detalhes do que você pretende fazer. Já adianto que pode ser uma boa usar um `TrimStart()` e/ou `TrimEnd()` pra remover os espaços do início e do fim da `string`. Dependendo do contexto, dá pra usar uma regex e pegar só  a parte numérica da `string` (acho um pouco de exagero, mas tudo depende de contexto) ou fazer um componente que só aceita números como entrada... Enfim, são infinitas possibilidades.

---

#### Sobre a mensagem de erro

A mensagem de erro em português é meio idiota mesmo e o pior é que ela é assim desde que eu conheço .NET.

A mensagem:

> A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto

Na verdade, deveria ser

> A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato **correto**

A mensagem original, é:

> Input string was not in a correct format