# Additional information: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto

Tags: c#

O que ha de errado com meu código?

```
conexao.conectarBD();
conectar.Open();
comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

comando = new SqlCommand("INSERIR_CLIENTE", conectar);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODIGO", Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text));
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOME", txtNome.Text);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEFONE", txtTelefone.Text);

comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("DEU BOM!");
```

Comment: `INSERIR_CLIENTE` é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

O que há de errado é que **`txtCodigo.Text`** tem um valor que **não pôde ser convertido para `int`**.

[Veja essa resposta para mais detalhes.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166608/18246)